# Cannot delete registered XSD schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle, xsd, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds, oracle19c

I am having trouble with deleting one XSD schema from my Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0.

So the problem is I have 64 XSD schemas to register but first I need to remove all the ones that were registered before so I have a clean USER_XML_SCHEMAS table.

I managed to delete all of the registered schemas using the `exec DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA(schemaurl => :schema_url ,delete_option  => 4);` command¸except one.

Only for one schema I am getting this error:

```
Error starting at line : 25 in command -
BEGIN DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA(schemaurl => 'PORR_MT049016UV.xsd',delete_option  => 4); END;
Error report -
ORA-31000: Resource 'PORR_MT049016UV.xsd' is not an XDB schema document
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA_INT", line 122
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA", line 106
ORA-06512: at line 1
31000. 00000 -  "Resource '%s' is not an XDB schema document"
*Cause:    The given schema URL does not refer to a registered XDB schema
*Action:   Make sure the specified schema has been registered in XDB
```

And the thing I for sure know that is XDB schema document when I try this query:

```
select * from xdb.xdb$schema x
where x.xmldata.schema_owner='HALO'
  and x.xmldata.schema_url='PORR_MT049016UV.xsd';
```

It returns this:
[image: query result]

And when I run this query it returns no rows.

```
SELECT ANY_PATH FROM RESOURCE_VIEW WHERE ANY_PATH LIKE '%PORR_MT049016UV.xsd';
```

Does anyone have any idea how to remove the registered schema from USER_XML_SCHEMAS and
xdb.xdb$schema tables?

Note: I do not have SYS access to the DB unfortunately as it is AWS hosted.

Thanks in advance!